# How do I before_filter a Module::Class::method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a custom Module on my Rails project, and I want it to be a before_filter, is there
a way I can do?

```
before_filter TokenGenerator::Generator.generate_token("mytoken")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a [block as a `before_filter`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#other-ways-to-use-filters):

```
before_filter do |controller|
    TokenGenerator::Generator.generate_token("mytoken")
end
```

Or you could create a separate class:

```
class TokenFilter
    def self.filter(controller)
        TokenGenerator::Generator.generate_token("mytoken")
    end
end

#...

before_filter TokenFilter
```

Or the usual method:

```
before_filter :token_generator

#...

private

def token_generator
    TokenGenerator::Generator.generate_token("mytoken")
end
```

Comment: Is listing `:token_generator` under private a separation of concerns issue or security issue (or both)? I'm leaning towards the former because without an explicit route, it wouldn't be accessible unless directly redirected to.. right? I guess I haven't read enough into the rails internals here.

Comment: @Adam: For me it is a cleanliness issue, the `token_generator` method isn't part of the controller class's external interface so it shouldn't be part of the class's Ruby interface either.

Answer (score 4):

You could create a delegator method to generate_token, then use the delegator method with the before filter...

```
before_filter :generate_token

def generate_token
  TokenGenerator::Generator.generate_token("mytoken")
end
```